# How do I convert this format of date time?

Tags: c#, datetime-format

What is the datetime format is this? and how can I convert to a normal datetime to be used in c# or sql?

2017-03-31T15:20:32.620436-04:00

Comment: Duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the ISO standard formatting, and you should be able to parse it into a `DateTime` object using:

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-31T15:20:32.620436-04:00");

var dateString = parsedDate.ToString("O");
// dateString: "2017-03-31T12:20:32.6204360-07:00"
//  Note the time has been changed to my local time zone
```